# Using join table or path expression with JPQL and Hibernate has the same effect?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Good evening,

Let my pojo Athor be:

```
public class Author {
  private long id;
  private String name;

  @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Editor editor;
}
```

I'd like to know if is there any difference, like performance, executions, etc between this two JPQL queries using Hibernate:

```
select a.name, b.name from Author a inner join a.editor e where a.id = 1;
```

and

```
select a.name, a.editor.name from Athor a where a.id = 1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the first one uses two tables and the later just one...

Comment: I don't think so, I'll rewrite my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Hackerman as you can see, my table Author only has Id from Editor. To retrieve the name information it must to get it in Editor table.

Comment: In your first query you have an `inner join` clause, without the `on` condition...that's a `cross join`...are you following me or not?

Comment: @Hackerman I understand, but and in the another, how it retrieves the Editor name?

Comment: Both (if they were fixed) would probably have the same performance. Which depends mainly on the database configuration (indices, etc.). Measure, and you'll see.